# how to keypress a random string using vbs every time in this existing code

Tags: vbscript

Here is my code

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "john@text"
```

What i want is that every time i run the vbs file the the text or number between " and @  should be random. john@text should be random every time for example 6534@text, aqwe@text, etc.

Comment: Generate a random number that represents the ASCII values of the legal (i.e. alphabetic) characters and then convert those numbers into an array of character and then into a string.

Comment: how to keypress if the string  is generated?

Answer (score -2):

Use randomly generated integers to represent ASCII characters and then convert the byte array into a string. Example:

```
Dim randomWord As String
Dim randomWordAsByteArray(1 To 4) As Byte

Randomize
Dim charNumber As Integer
For charNumber = 1 To 4
    randomWordAsByteArray(charNumber) = Int((26 * Rnd) + 1) + 96
Next

randomWord = StrConv(randomWordAsByteArray, vbUnicode)
```

Comment: VBScript is typeless, the `As` keyword in declarations syntax is invalid. Also, VBScript doesn’t support Array ranges syntax.